# how can I have my table to have a sticky header and have overflow horizontally?

Tags: css

the problem is I want the scrollbar only for the page and not the table. Right now, there is scrollbar in the table and I want to remove it.

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div className='table-responsive h-screen'>
  <Table className='table-flush align-middle' hover>
    <thead className='thead-light'>
      <tr className='sticky top-0'>
        <th className='px-2 text-left' data-sort='name' scope='col'>
          <CampaignListTitle title='ID' keyword='id' />
        </th>
        <th className='max-w-lg px-2 text-left' data-sort='name' scope='col'>
          <CampaignListTitle title={translation.CAMPAIGN__CAMPAIGN_NAME} keyword='name' />
        </th>

        </th>
        <tbody className='list'>
          <td className='text-xs'>
            <div>{campaign.id}</div>
          </td>
          <td className='text-xs'>
            <div className='w-[30rem] whitespace-normal'>
              <div>{campaign.name}</div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tbody>
  </Table>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using a framework for the CSS ? can we get more infos ?

Comment: I'm using both bootstrap and tailwind (I know its stupid but yeah) @Asmoth

Comment: Read about [position-sticky-and-table-headers](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/)

Comment: I made a snippet of your code but notice the table `</th>` is malformed there

Comment: Suggest to make this JUST rendered HTML and make a properly reproducible example of this.

Answer (score 0):

Headers can be made sticky based on this CSS Tricks Article: [Position Sticky and Table Headers](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/)

The scrolling is a different matter but should be simple to disable scrollbars with some targeted CSS

```css
table {
  position: relative;
}

table>thead>tr>th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  
  /*Bootstrap override */
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>G</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>I</th>
      <th>J</th>
      <th>K</th>
      <th>L</th>
      <th>M</th>
      <th>N</th>
      <th>O</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table element will have a height according to its content so maybe your parent of table element has a specific height that cause the scroll behavior of table so maybe `height: auto` for both table and its parent. Your parent has `h-screen` class so it cause the scroll behavior